# Excel. Conditional formatting on data points based on a separate row

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I want to create a scatter plot chart where each data point is different (different icon, different color, etc.) based on the value in a column.

I'm learning classification models, and I want to make a scatter plot in Excel that (1) maps two independent variables in the x and y axes, and (2) changes the data point based on a third independent variable.

Example: I have a table with three columns: Errors (spelling errors in an e-mail), Recipients (number of recipients in the To section of an e-mail), and Spam (1 for spam messages, 2 for non-spam messages). It looks like this:

```
Errors, Recipients, Spam
20,200,1
18,175,1
32,100,1
15,123,1
2,10,0
5,8,0
9,27,0
15,20,1
15,20,0
8,300,0
9,357,1
```

At a glance, messages with high errors *and* high recipients are more likely to be spam. Messages with low errors and low recipients are likely not to be spam. Messages with high and low mixes are less predictable. I want to show that in a scatter plot.

I can make a scatter plot with Errors on the Y-axis and Recipients on the X-axis. What I also need to do is change each data point to be a "+" or "-" based on whether the Spam cell is a 1 or 0.

I know it's possible to change the appearance of all data points, and to manually change individual data points. But is it possible to automatically, conditionally change the appearance of data points based on a column value?

Comment: You can't do it in that exact way. I'd split the list to two series based on spam value, so don't need to check each point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel doesn't have conditional formatting for Charts (although it really should).  The best way to accomplish this is to:
  1) Convert your data to an Excel Table (which should do every time).
  2) Add two helper columns, + and -.
  3) Add this formula to the helper columns
    `+=IF([@[ Spam]]=1,[@[ Recipients]],NA())`
    `-=IF([@[ Spam]]=0,[@[ Recipients]],NA())`
  4) Create your chart using the + and - columns for your Y data.

Also, you'll want to consider how to deal with overlapping points (e.g. 15,20).  You can adjust the plot order in the select data dialog box, or consider different symbology that will deal with overlaps (e.g. + and x).